# what to do for performance when using a slug in an url?

Tags: mysql, rest, database-design

I see lots of websites using slugs in URLs, like these:

[catalog-product id="179"] ---> [catalog-product slug="5oz-modelling-hammer"]

I'd like to know: compared to Int search, will String search in MySQL cause performance problems?

I know about indexed fields, but I wonder whether it will cause a problem because the query is run whenever a page is visited. 
And what is the best practice in table design or eve what are other back-end techniques I should know about?

Comment: I notice the URL of stackoverflow , It's look like it using both id & Slug approach. What kind of case will it be good for using this approach ?

Comment: Text, numbers, it's all bits. If the column is properly indexed, the performance difference between comparing e.g 16 and 256 bits should be irrelevant. Stack Overflow uses both because you can *edit* questions and change their title.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question gets asked often in many forms:

- What's faster, `require` or `include`?
- What's faster, `echo $a . $b` or `echo $a, $b`?
- What's faster, `DATE` or `VARCHAR`?
- What's faster, `number % 2` or `number & 1`?

Computers as fast enough to make the answer irrelevant. You'd need to do those operations like 1 billion times per page load to make a difference and, in that case, you'd have bigger problems. Performance bottlenecks tend to be fairly obvious:

- Link 50MB worth of pictures in your HTML
- Run SQL in loops and flood the DB server with hundreds of identical queries
- Read huge XML files in memory

To sum up, whether to use IDs, slugs or both is basically a design decision that does not depend on how fast the server is.

- Just numbers can be unacceptable for an e-commerce site that relies heavily on SEO
- Just slugs can be unacceptable for a community driven site where the page title can be freely modified